# problème with segmention fault

Tags: c

Hello I have a problem with my code: I would like create a class in C, but I have a problem when I create a method. My method produces a `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`.

my class:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct test2d {
    int a, b;
    int (*add)(struct test2d c);
};

extern const struct test2dClass {
    struct test2d (*new)(int a, int b);
} test2d;
```

my code:

```
#include <math.h>
#include "test2d.h"

static int add(struct test2d c) {
    return 'f';
}

static struct test2d new(int a, int b) {
    return (struct test2d){ .a = a, .b = b };
}

const struct test2dClass test2d = { .new = &new };

int main(int argc, char argv[]) {
    struct test2d c = test2d.new(23, 4);
    printf("valeur a : %d, b: %d\n", c.a, c.b);
    printf("%d\n dfsd", c.add(c));
}
```

console output: `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`

Comment: Intuitively, I feel like your test2d method needs to `malloc` the memory required for your returned `struct test2d`

Comment: The `add` function that you define is not used.  You need to assign it to the `c.add` function pointer.

Comment: `add` isn't initialized but is used. Your naming style is crazy hard to read.

Comment: @stark how should I define a method add and where?

Comment: `return (struct test2d){.a=a, .b=b, .add = add};`.

Comment: Side note : `int main(int argc, char argv[])` should be `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the `new` constructor: you do not initialize the `add` member, so the compiler initializes it to a null pointer. Hence calling `c.add` has undefined behavior.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "test2d.h"

static int add(struct test2d c) {
    return 'f';
}

static struct test2d new(int a, int b) {
    return (struct test2d){ .a = a, .b = b, .add = add };
}

const struct test2dClass test2d = { .new = new };

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    struct test2d c = test2d.new(23, 4);
    printf("valeur a : %d, b: %d\n", c.a, c.b);
    printf("%d\n dfsd", c.add(c));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Je ne comprends pas le besoin d'une telle architecture, ce code est à peu près aussi hermétique pour beaucoup de programmeurs C que ce commentaire pour les anglophones :)